# I received this code error each time I tried to sart may project on vscode using parcel : 'ERR_DLOPEN_FAILED'

Tags: javascript, parceljs

I'm new to parcel and I'm following a tutorial I downloaded parcel last version is not working I tried the version the instructor using but the same thing happened the

the output in the terminal is

```
Error: The specified module could not be found.
\\?\\D:\\Downloads\\starter\\node_modules@parcel\\source-map\\parcel_sourcemap_node\\artifacts\\index.win32-x64-msvc.node
at Module.\_extensions..node (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1243:18)
at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1037:32)
at Module.\_load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:878:12)
at Module.require (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1061:19)
at require (D:\\Downloads\\starter\\node_modules\\v8-compile-cache\\v8-compile-cache.js:159:20)
at Object.\<anonymous\> (D:\\Downloads\\starter\\node_modules@parcel\\source-        map\\parcel_sourcemap_node\\index.js:15:18)
at Module.\_compile (D:\\Downloads\\starter\\node_modules\\v8-compile-cache\\v8-compile-cache.js:192:30)
at Module.\_extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1213:10)
at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1037:32)
at Module.\_load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:878:12) {
code: 'ERR_DLOPEN_FAILED'
}
```

Answer (score 0):

ive had the same error before,
i removed my node_modules package and then ran again, this worked for me